# Sql query for count with inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables with the following columns

**messages:**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM messages;
+-----------+-----------+------------+
| id | user | direction | added      |
+----+------+-----------+------------+
|  1 |  1   | 0         | 1602333584 |
|  2 |  1   | 1         | 1602353792 |
|  3 |  1   | 0         | 1602364418 |
+---------+-------------+------------+
```

**users:**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM users;
+-----------+-----------+
| id | name | modified  |
+----+------+-----------+
|  1 | test | 160201127 |
+----+------+-----------+
```

I am trying to count the number of rows in the 'messages' table with direction = 1 for a specific user id 1 where user.modified is smaller than messages.added. I am using the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS mcount 
  FROM messages 
  JOIN users 
    ON users.id = messages.user 
   AND users.modified < messages.added 
 WHERE messages.user = 1 
   AND direction = 1
```

It always returns mcount as 0. What should be the correct query in this case?

Comment: Please add example data. What data type are `added` and`modified`?

Comment: The query seems to be fine according to your description. Please add example data as suggested.

Comment: Why not provide the data in the format suggested?

Comment: *It always returns mcount as 0.* I don't believe. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=72a4623502221df41c5447335cb407a0)

Comment: PS. If `direction` may be 0 or 1 only then you may simply use SUM() over it.

Comment: The mysql returns 1 for your example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=005bd15653878ed920fdba28826c1fd1